# Do the vacation packages in Expedia.ca and Aircanadavacations.com have an included tour?

Tags: online-resources, bookings, vacations

As in the title, I haven't booked vacation package before.

So I am getting little confused, what is really included in their vacation packages?
Is it just the hotel and flight ticket? Do they have a tour to bring you to different places in the city to do sightseeing?

In Expedia, for example, the Mexican vacation packages state a different tour operator, but in the details it only listed about the Resort building and services they have.

If I want to book a vacation package that has hotel + flight + tour online, departing from Toronto, are there any sites that can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**They include what is says in the description and rarely more.** Each offering is different, so there is no general answer to your title question.

When booking with Expedia, make sure to open the details page, it always has additional information and frequently additional options such as including meals, larger or better placed rooms, etc. Some vacations even include a rental car but you can always count on flight plus hotel, and *almost* always transport from the airport to your hotel and back at the destination.

Expedia has the custom vacation option which lets you choose components and add them together with a discount. For that choose 'Build Your Own' under vacation packages. Tours are available to for some destinations.

While I understand the piece of mind of booking all at once, there is little risk **booking the tour at the destination** and it is highly advantageous. You will often be able to get a better price and considerably more options to tailor your experience. Even just being able to book after knowing the weather more accurately can save you from taking a tour in pouring rain.